# Uso de "Qual que" está correto?

Tags: pronomes

O uso da expressão "qual que", associando dois pronomes interrogativos, tem se transformado em verdadeira epidemia, infectando principalmente repórteres do meio televisivo.  Não vejo justificativa para essa associação. Ou perguntamos "qual caminho leva à Roma" ou "que caminho leva à Roma", mas nunca "qual que".  Opiniões?

Comment: Não conheço o fenômeno ainda, você poderia dar o link de algum exemplo (vídeo ou reportagem)?

Comment: Basta assistir a qualquer telejornal da rede globo ou da globonews.  A apresentadora da GloboNews Aline Midlej é useira e vezeira do citado vício de linguagem

Comment: Iriel, concordo com o stafusa: esta pergunta precisa de exemplos. Se este uso é verdadeiramente uma epidemia, será fácil encontrares um par de frases-exemplo para citar... :)

Comment: Já agora: esta pergunta é só sobre [tag:português-brasileiro]? Ou também estás interessada em respostas de [tag:português-europeu]? Existe "diferença transatlântica" neste caso... :)

Comment: Acredito que tenha "se tornado uma epidemia" em determinados socioletos como, por exemplo, entre frequentadores de bailes funks.  Eu nunca ouvi esse tipo de construção apesar de, na minha profissão, conversar com mais de 20 pessoas diferentes por dia.

Comment: "Qual que é" utilizado pela maioria dos repórteres de São Paulo.

Answer (score 6):

A expressão é bastante encontrada em letras de *Funk* e *RAP* brasileiros.

> Qual que é?
>   Qual a tua?
>   Você se foi e a vida continua
>   Luz do sol me faz lembrar
>   Mas, meu amor, eu quero um tempo p'ra sonhar.
>                              — Armandinho (Reggae)

> Não sei qual que é,
>   Se me vêem, dão ré
>                              — Sabotagem

A depender do contexto, o uso está correto, sim. Também conhecida como *partícula expletiva* ou *realce*; *clivagem* ou *operador da construção clivada*<sup>1</sup>, este termo serve — basicamente — para realçar algo no texto. Como o termo possui função sintática nenhuma, pode ser retirado sem prejuízo.

**Exemplo:**

“Então, qual que é a verdade?” (Luiz Vilela) = Então qual é a verdade?

“Nós / é que vamos empurrando, dia a dia, sua cadeira de rodas.” (Mack-SP)

De acordo com um estudo realizado por Juliana Chrisóstomo, ”A segunda situação em que as clivadas aparecem é na sessão referente à concordância verbal, quando o sujeito é o pronome “quem” ou quando é o pronome “que”:

> Sou eu quem fala agora.
>   Sou eu quem falo agora.”

O termo *"qual que"* também pode aparecer quando o interlocutor utiliza a [zeugma](https://www.figurasdelinguagem.com/zeugma/) (figura de linguagem), que consiste na supressão de palavras ou de uma expressão, como, por exemplo:

> — Você gosta de poema?
>   — Sim, bastante.
>   — Qual [poema] que você mais gosta?

***Referências***

<sup>1 Cf. Mateus et al. 2003 — **Gramática da Língua Portuguesa**, Lisboa, Caminho: 687.</sup>
<sup>ALMEIDA, Juliana C. **Um estudo das estruturas clivadas do português.** [S. l.], 2011.
 Disponível em: http://bdm.unb.br/bitstream/10483/6567/1/2011_JulianaChrisostomoDeAlmeida.pdf. Acesso em: 15 ago. 2019.</sup>
<sup>MOLLICA, Maria C.; MOURA, Samara; LOFEUDO, Thaís P. **Qual (que) é a parte da Linguística que estuda a heterogeneidade da linguagem humana?: Clivagem e multifuncionalidade.** [S. l.], 2012.
 Disponível em: http://periodicos.letras.ufmg.br/index.php/relin/article/viewFile/2753/2708. Acesso em: 15 ago. 2019.</sup>
<sup>MIKOŁAJCZAK, Sylwia. **Os tipos das construções com clivagem em português.** [S. l.], 2003.
 Disponível em: https://pressto.amu.edu.pl/index.php/srp/article/download/10377/9934. Acesso em: 15 ago. 2019.</sup>
<sup>MARTINS, Ana. **Que, operador da construção clivada.** [S. l.], 18 mar. 2010.
 Disponível em: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-operador-da-construcao-clivada/27862. Acesso em: 15 ago. 2019.</sup>

Comment: Não dou mais votos a este post porque só posso dar +1.

Comment: A frase "Qual que é?" é gramaticalmente correta no Brasil? Em Portugal, precisa do "é" que foi omitido: «qual é?" => «qual [é que] é?»; ou mais fácil de perceber: «qual foi» => «qual é que foi».

Comment: @ANeves Subentende-se o verbo, neste caso. Não é recomendado usar quando necessitar de formalidade; mas, gramaticalmente falando, pode ser adicionada ou removida sem prejuizo semântico e gramatical. Aqui, no Brasil (ao menos na minha região), é comum ouvir: "o que que você quer?", "o que que aconteceu?" e afins.

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente esse o esclarecimento que eu queria. : )