# A letra "a" é masculino ou feminino?

Tags: gramática, feminino-masculino

Sou um falante nativo da lingua portuguesa (brasileiro). Estava conversando em português com um espanhol, o qual é meu amigo. Em certo ponto da conversa ele me perguntou

> "A palavra *hábito* possui acento **na** a?"

Nesse momento eu respondi

> "Tem acento sim, mas eu acho que a forma correta de se fazer a pergunta seria: *A palavra hábito possui acento **no** a?* Invés de ***na*** a."

Nós discutimos por uns 10 minutos sobre o que seria a forma correta, e infelizmente eu não possuia argumentos além da minha mera experiência de vida.

Tentei procurar online essa pergunta, se a letra "a" é masculino ou feminino mas não encontrei resposta.

Alguém sabe responder a essa questão?

PS: Para não acharem que sou mal educado, gostaria de deixar claro que meu amigo disse de forma clara "Por favor, se ouvir eu falar algo errado, por favor me corrija."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando queremos indicar que estamos nos referindo a primeira letra do alfabeto português, o *"A"* é utilizado como substantivo masculino. Portanto, o correto é:

> A palavra *hábito* possui acento n**o** "a"?

As letras — de modo geral, de acordo com a gramática — são consideras como *substantivo masculino*. Ou seja, o correto é: O "a", o "b", o "c", o "d", o "e" etc.

No entanto, a depender do contexto, podemos usar o artigo feminino, uma ou a, antes. Isso pode ocorrer quando utilizamos a figura de linguagem chamada [*zeugma*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/6138/2759), por exemplo.

> A palavra *hábito* possui acento na letra "a"?
>   Sim, há acento n**a** *[letra]* "a".

*Links:*
https://www.dicio.com.br/a/
https://dicionario.priberam.org/a
http://www.academia.org.br/nossa-lingua/busca-no-vocabulario