# como é que se diz vs como se diz

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras

In Pimsleur's courses he teaches, for instance:

```
como é que se diz "NNN"?
```

instead of

```
como se diz "NNN"?
```

I've heard other questions that are formed in a simillar manner, with an additional `é que` and `o que` too, if I've heard correctly.

What are these `é que` and `o que` for?

Comment: O *é que* serve como uma partícula de realce, para destacar a pergunta. Essa partícula é opcional. As frases "Como é que se diz..." e "Como se diz..." estão corretas e possuem o mesmo significado.

Comment: As Valdeir Psr says above, it's just for emphasis, not much different from the *do* in "I *do* know the answer.".

Comment: @stafusa  It is very different from "I do know the answer".  The latter makes a semantic difference when used.

Comment: I think you're mistaken, @Centaurus . Do you know of an example where "I do know" is not an emphatic "I know"? But I agree with Artefacto, the "é que" isn't really much for emphasis, but rather just a colloquial way of saying it.

Comment: @Stafusa   Vou repetir meu comentário de forma mais clara, mas não pretendo discutir língua Inglesa aqui no PL. A diferença entre "como é que se diz..." e "como se diz..." é bem diferente da diferença entre "I know" e "I do know".

Comment: Se você pudesse me informar num chat, então eu agradeceria - ou então não comece discussões que não pretende continuar. Sobre serem situações diferentes, é o que eu já havia comentado: que concordo com a descrição do Artefacto, que explicitamente afirma isso.

Comment: Boa gente, os comentários servem para pedir esclarecimentos, sugerir melhorias, ou apontar problemas com uma pergunta/resposta; e não para responder. Isto podia tudo ser uma série de comentários numa resposta do @ValdeirPsr ... ; )

Comment: Adendo: "I do know" e "I know" podem ser diferente na língua inglesa, mas o sentido de "como é que se diz" e "como se diz" é exatamente igual na língua portuguesa, mudando apenas a ênfase. Lembrando que a [partícula expletiva](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/delta/v29n2/05.pdf) tem nenhuma função sintática na oração. Também já escrevi uma [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/6138/2759) que aborda a partícula de realce. @ANeves, não escrevi uma resposta, porque não me senti confortável para escrever em inglês. Então decidir postar um comentário para, talvez, servir como um pontapé inicial

Comment: Não tem mal, @ValdeirPsr. Da próxima podes até responder em Português, que vale na mesma; ou se achares preferível que tenha uma versão inglesa, deixa um comentário na resposta que alguém adiciona. :) Se não estiveres muito à vontade, responde como community wiki. A malta vai apreciar. :)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Você se junta ao Centauros para afirmar que há uma diferença e, como ele, não oferece referência alguma. O que acho é: "Since this sort of do-support is optional, you could remove do from any of these examples and they'd still make sense. **They'd just be less emphatic.**", nessa [resposta](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10212).

Comment: @stafusa Não afirmei que as sentenças em inglês são diferentes, afirmei que **podem** ser diferentes (sou um bárbaro no que tange a línguas estrangeiras) e que, na língua portuguesa, o sentido das orações da pergunta é igual, inclusive postei dois *links*: Um estudo acadêmico que aborda a partícula expletiva e uma resposta que escrevi sobre o mesmo assunto.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr OK, só um mal entendido, então. Eu tinha interpretado teu "podem" como em "Elas podem ser fortes, mas não são resistentes.", ou seja, confirmando que "são diferentes" e não que "talvez sejam".

Comment: @ANeves Será que não seria o caso de transferir esses comentários para um chat (ou apagá-los)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two sentences:

> (1) Como **é que** se diz "NNN"?
>   (2) Como se diz "NNN"?

Are equivalent in meaning. There is no particular "emphasis" in (1). The difference is one of register: a sentence like (1) is typical of the spoken language and (2) of the written language.

Wh-questions with *é que* developed both in European and Brazilian Portuguese in the second half of the 1800s. It was not a feature of the previous period of the language, called Classical Portuguese.

Since the second half of 1900s, questions with *é que* are strongly predominant in spoken European Portuguese; the main exception being questions with the copula *ser* like:

> (3) Qual é o maior?

Although you could also see a question like:

> (4) Qual é que é o maior?

On the other hand, it would not be idiomatic to replace a sentence like *Quando é que vens?* by *Quando vens?* -- the second sounds quite a bit off.

One important difference between the two constructions is that the relative position of the verb and the subject change in the two constructions (this applies only to European Portuguese). Without *é que*, an inversion is mandatory in direct questions:

> (5) Como se chama o rapaz?
>   (6) Quando vai a empresa investir em Espanha?

This is the same movement that occurs in English: notice that in (6) only the auxiliary verb moves.

Questions with *é que* are generally in the Subject-Verb order:

> (7) Como é que o rapaz se chama?
>   (8) Quando é que a empresa vai investir em Espanha?

Although the Verb-Subject configuration also occurs with [unaccusative verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb) or, likewise, passive constructions:

> (9) Como é que é se partiu a chávena?
>   (10) Como é que a chávena se partiu?
>   (11) Como é que isso aconteceu?
>   (12) Como é que aconteceu isso?
>   (13) Onde é que foi enterrado o corpo?
>   (14) Onde é que o corpo foi enterrado?

Reference: [A Sintaxe Diacrônica das Interrogativas-Q do Português](http://repositorio.unicamp.br/bitstream/REPOSIP/269151/1/Lopes-Rossi_MariaAparecidaGarcia_D.pdf)

Comment: why in the speech the longer formed is used rather than the shorter one?