# Usar dois "quês" seguidos é correto? O "quê" anterior ao segundo recebe acento circunflexo?

Tags: acentuação

Como nas formas a seguir, qual seria a forma correta e por quê?

*O quê que aconteceu?*

*O que que aconteceu?*

Comment: Talvez o ajude: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/6138/2759

Comment: Na linguagem coloquial falada apenas, é muito usual e comum. Na escrita, nunca use.

Answer (score 1):

Nenhuma está correta, mas a que tem um "quê" está mais errada.

## Construção correta da frase

Podes perguntar só com um "que":

> - O que aconteceu?

Ou usar a forma mais longa e acrescentar "é que":

> - O que **é que** aconteceu?

Isto é uma construção comum, em que se acrescenta um "é que" opcional para dar ênfase à pergunta:

> - Qual [é que] preferes?
> - Quanto [é que] custa?
> - Que [é que] se passa?
> - Quando [é que] posso ir para a piscina?
> - A que horas [é que] posso ir para a piscina?

Este "é que" chama-se uma partícula expletiva ou de realce.

## Usos válidos de "quê"

Então e porque está errado usar ali um "quê"?
Poderia esse "quê" ser usado noutra construção?
Analisemos.

O [dicionário Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/qu%C3%AA) diz que "quê", para além de ser o «nome da letra Q ou q», é:

> quê (latim *quem*)
>
> nome masculino:
>
> 1. Dificuldade, complicação (ex.: ainda há uns quês por resolver).
> 2. Alguma coisa (ex.: acho que isto tem um quê de subversão).
>
> pronome interrogativo:
>
> 3. Expressão usada para questionar o que foi dito anteriormente ou como pedido de repetição do que foi dito (ex.: Quê? Não entendi.). = COMO, O QUÊ
>
> interjeição:
>
> 4. Expressão usada, com entoação interrogativa, para indicar espanto ou contrariedade (ex.: Quê?! O filme ainda não começou?). = O QUÊ

"quê", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/qu%C3%AA [consultado em 01-07-2020].

Daqui, parece claro que:

- O uso para 1. e 2. é como qualquer outro nome/substantivo. Só caberá onde pudesse ser substituído por um substantivo equivalente (de acordo com o contexto): "questão", "ponto", "pormenor", "detalhe".
- O uso para 3. e 4. é isolado - a frase é composta *só* pelo "quê": «Quê? O quê?».

Então, concluímos que o "quê" não tem nenhuma função ou significado que lhe permita ser usado numa frase parecida com:

> O *quê que aconteceu?

Comment: Mesmo sendo uma partícula expletiva, ela não é recomendada se você está redigindo um texto formal ou está utilizando-a em um ambiente formal.

Comment: Concordo, não fica bem usá-la num contexto formal.

Comment: Será que está errada mesmo, ANeves? Me parece que "Qual que preferes?" é correto, então por que não "O que que aconteceu?"?

Comment: @stafusa, se entendi https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/particulas-expletivas-ou-realce.htm corretamente, “o que que aconteceu” está correto. Basicamente, pelo que entendi, “que” e “é que” podem ser partículas. O Houssaiss diz “b) ainda como expletivo, é corrente no Brasil em frases interrogativas informais, tanto diretas (o que que você pretende fazer?) quanto indiretas (não entendiam o que que ele tinha na cabeça)”.

Comment: @Schilive É o que penso também, por isso quero sugerir ao ANeves que mude o início de sua resposta que, no momento, é "Nenhuma está correta".

Comment: @stafusa não acho que "qual que queres" esteja correto. Eu diria ou a. "qual queres" ou b. "qual é que queres". Continuo a achar que ambas estão erradas. É possível que isto se aplique a português-europeu mas seja diferente em português brasileiro - se for esse o caso, eu ia adorar aparecesse uma resposta sobre pt-BR. :)

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil, acho que estás certo, pois ouço mais portugueses dizendo “é que” do que brasileiros, onde geralmente colocariam “que” em vez de “é que”, e o Houaiss colocou esse “que que” como em “que que ele fez?” como uso brasileiro.

Comment: Não gosto muito [desse artigo](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/particulas-expletivas-ou-realce.htm). Os quatro primeiros exemplos parecem-me fracos ou quase errados. Os exemplos do parágrafo dos «que» parecem-me corretos, mas nenhum... "aceita" a forma _é que_ - por isso não são equivalentes aos primeiros exemplos que são (deviam ser) todos formas "é que". (E os pronomes «se» e «me», a serem partículas expletivas, pedem a companhia de «te lhe vos lhes»; não é?)

Comment: @Schilive esse exemplo do Houaiss parece um **ótimo** ponto de partida para uma resposta sobre pt-BR. :) Força, mostra-nos uma boa resposta do atlântico oeste!

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil, não sei se é boa, mas é uma tentativa,

Answer (score 1):

## Análise

### Introdução

A palavra *que* «Poderá, ainda, se apresentar como uma partícula expletiva ou de realce quando puder ser retirada da expressão sem prejuízo» ([1](https://www2.jf.jus.br/pergamumweb/vinculos/000025/00002546.pdf)).

Primeiramente, o que é uma partícula? Como bem define o Dicio, «Nome genérico de vocábulos gramaticais de pequeno porte, normalmente átonos, como pronomes (me, te), preposições (a, com, de) [...]», logo, *que* pode se encaixar, já que é átono, não tem acento, e é pequeno, monossílabo. Segundamente, o que é algo expletivo? Na lingüística, expletivo é uma palavra cuja única função é enfatizar a frase, sem mudar o sentido dela, i.e., se retirássemos uma palavra expletiva duma frase, seu sentido não se teria alterado.

### Analisando

Como sabemos que *que* pode ser classificado como partícula expletiva e como identificar uma partícula expletiva, analisemos as tuas duas frases:

> a1) «O quê que aconteceu?»
>
> b1) «O que que aconteceu?»

Retirando-lhes os *que*'s:

> a2) «O quê aconteceu?»
>
> b2) «O que aconteceu?»

Usa-se *quê* (2) no lugar de *que* quando no final de frase, substantivo masculino, equivalente a *coisa* ou *complicação*, ou interjeição, como em *Quê! So' lá sócio da Light?!*, então, *quê* em a2) não é interjeição nem está no final da frase, portanto é substantivo. Assim comparemos «a coisa/complicação que aconteceu?» com «a coisa/complicação aconteceu?». Se a primeira for equivalente à segunda, esse *que* é uma partícula expletiva. A primeira frase também pode ser equivalente a «foi a coisa o que aconteceu?», o que não é equivalente à segunda, então, *que* em a1) pode ser ou não uma partícula expletiva, dependendo da interpretação.

A palavra *que* em b2) pode ser ([3](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/que)) um pronome relativo (ex.: «o livro **que** lhe deu se estragou, **o que** é natural») ou interrogativo (ex.: «**que** carro é este?»), um determinante interrogativo (ex.: «(o) **que** vais fazer?»), advérbio de intensidade (ex.: «que beleza!») ou conjunção. Já que *que* está acompanhado do artigo *o*, pode apenas ser um pronome relativo ou pronome interrogativo. Como pronome relativo, «o que aconteceu?» poderia ser resposta a «Maria andar sozinha», sendo equivalente a «Maria andar sozinha aconteceu?»; se assim for, b1) é equivalente a «Maria andar sozinha que aconteceu?», cujo, como visto no parágrafo anterior, *que* pode ser ou não uma partícula expletiva, já que *Maria andar sozinha* é uma locução substantiva. Como pronome interrogativo, segundo *que* em a2) seria partícula expletiva, pois a1) e a2) seriam equivalentes em significado.

### Conclusão

Ergo, se considerarmos ou não o uso da partícula expletiva *que* correto, ambas as frases estão corretas. Imagino eu que estavas querendo saber pensando em *que* como pronome interrogativo. Se assim for, a1) está errada, assim como disse ANeves, e b1) está errada se considerares *que* como partícula expletiva errado.

## Formalidade

Formalidade não é fato, mas sim consenso. Ou seja, se todos considerarem *que* como partícula expletiva informal, assim é. Infelizmente não podemos entrevistar toda a gente em Portugal ou todo o mundo no Brasil para saber o que pensam, mas principalmente com a própria experiência e puxões de orelha alguém entende melhor o consenso.

O consenso, brasileiro, que conheço é de *que* como partícula expletiva ser informal e principalissimamente oral. Pelos comentários do ANeves, que creio que seja português, em Portugal, *que* como partícula expletiva é considerado errado.

## Notas Finais

Neste texto, eu estou falando exclusivamente de *que* como partícula expletiva, ou seja, eu não estou falando de *é que*.

Answer (score -1):

Não, isso se chama **queísmo**¹, que é o excesso do emprego do conectivo "que". Se você utilizar apenas a frase "O que aconteceu?", verá que ela por si só faz sentido sem a necessidade de um segundo "que", que estaria incorreto.

Usar dois "quês" seguidos é incorreto baseado nas seguintes afirmações:

1. O "quê" é utilizado apenas no final de frases², com exceção das situações em que ele representa um substantivo.
2. Tomando como base a afirmativa acima, se fôssemos aplicar dois "quês" seguidos, teríamos "que que". Portanto, isso estaria totalmente errado pelo simples fato de serem duas palavras repetidas em sequência.

Em suma, o correto é utilizar o simples "**O que aconteceu?**".

¹ [Queísmo](https://www.stoodi.com.br/blog/2017/04/28/como-eu-faco-para-evitar-o-queismo-na-hora-de-escrever-redacao/)

² [Diferença entre quê e que](https://www.todamateria.com.br/que-ou-que/)

Comment: Ó chefe, esse paper da SciELO que linkaste diz que o queísmo é a «**omissão de preposição** antes da conjunção-complementador "que" em complementos oracionais oblíquos finitos". Mas esta resposta fala de "quês" a mais, não da omissão de nada. Acho que é preciso que a resposta explique o que é o queísmo.

Comment: Obrigado por avisar. Não sei onde foi parar o URL correto do arquivo PDF que eu ia linkar aqui. Fiz a edição.

Comment: A definição de queísmo não parece ser "uso excessivo de ques", mas sim "omissão da preposição antes do que". Este artigo do CiberDúvidas confirma: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/uso-de-de-que-de-novo-queismo-e-dequeismo/19156 Parece que o uso comum da palavra "queísmo" é com esse primeiro sentido, erradamente... mas na minha opinião devíamos evitar isso. Da mesma maneira que acho que *não devemos* chamar "[número redondo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_redondo)" a múltiplos de potências de 10.

Comment: Antes de afirmar, confirmei com minha professora de lingua portuguesa e em alguns sites da internet. Muitos confirmam que queísmo é o excesso da palavra "que".

Comment: Chanp, você teria alguma fonte (que não blogs ou tua professora) que confirmem seu uso da palavra "queísmo"? Porque o [dicionário](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/que%C3%ADsmo/), assim como [esse artigo](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317231988_Dequeismo_and_queismo_in_Portuguese_and_Spanish) fazem o uso do termo com o significado que o @ANevesthinksSEisevil descreve.

Answer (score -1):

Resumirei para vocês.
"O que que (qui) está fazendo?"
Seja a classificação gramatical que for dos "ques" (sinônimo, substântivo, pronome, preposição, conjunção etc.), serás uma redundância. Basta substituir os "ques".
A causa disso é o nosso vício de pronúncia (o que qui tem).
Existem outros exêmplos: vou ir (irei), vou "vim" (virei). Nesse caso, se vou, irei a algum lugar e se venho (vim), virei de algum lugar, certo? Como ir vindo a algum lugar? Fisicamente é impossível. São direções opostas.